# "Caller rejected because extension not found" in asterisk

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, voip, asterisk

I'm an asterisk newbie and I've just installed it on my ubuntu 12.04 server with `sudo apt-get install asterisk`. I'm following the tutorial for asterisk from here: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Basic+PBX+Functionality

which describes setting up the most simplest PBX with two sip phones demo-alice and demo-bob. I've followed the instruction to the dot, however, when I make a call from demo-bob to demo-alice I get:

```
[Feb  5 13:23:03] NOTICE[13667]: chan_sip.c:22622 handle_request_invite:
Call from 'demo-bob' (192.168.1.2:5060) to extension '6001' rejected 
because extension not found in context 'users'.
```

However, the dialplan gives me:

```
*CLI> dialplan show users
[ Context 'users' created by 'pbx_config' ]
  '6001' =>         1. Dial(SIP/demo-alice)                       [pbx_config]
  '6002' =>         1. Dial(SIP/demo-bob)                         [pbx_config]

-= 2 extensions (2 priorities) in 1 context. =-
```

So I clearly HAVE extension 6001 in context users. What am I doing wrong? Please help?

Some more info:

I've reloaded the config and dialplan with `sip reload` and `dialplan reload`. I'm using asterisk 1.8. This is the output of `sip show peers`:

```
*CLI> sip show peers
Name/username              Host                                    Dyn Forcerport ACL    Port     Status     
demo-alice/demo-alice      192.168.1.12                             D   N   A  5060     Unmonitored 
demo-bob/demo-bob          192.168.1.2                              D   N   A  5060     Unmonitored 
2 sip peers [Monitored: 0 online, 0 offline Unmonitored: 2 online, 0 offline]
```

Comment: try something like `channel originate SIP/thufir extension 18003569377@outbound` from the console.  You'll have to to modify for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Check context by

```
asterisk -rx "dialplan show 6001@users"
```

If not help, enable sip debug or general debug to ensure you are calling 6001.

Answer (score -1):

I had the issue as well, it was related to the Class of Service not containing the Outgoing line. When adding the newly made outgoing line to the default Class of Service, the issue disappeared.